# Fade in and out without the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.quotes {display: none;}​
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>​

<script>
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works as intended, it's supposed to loop, but I'd like to get rid of the loop. If anyone can help it'd be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I would like it so once it gets to the second quote it doesn't fade out and stays there.

Comment: Be more specific... What loop do you want to get rid of?

Comment: Seems to me that without the loop it won't work as intended.

Comment: Since I think I originally wrote this code as part of some other answer, please describe what you are trying to accomplish.  This code was intended to display alternate quotes with one fading out, then the other fading in - repeating forever and it will cycle through as many quotes as you put in the HTML.  That's what it was designed to do.  If you have a different need, you will have to describe what exactly you want it to do before anyone can help you.  As your question stands now, it will need to be closed as "Unclear What You're Asking" unless you can clarify your question.

Comment: I would like it so once it gets to the second quote it stays there and doesn't fade out. Sorry for not being specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have commented you don't want to fade-out the last quote, I think just have an `if` condition to check if it's last quote, if it's don't say to `fade-out`.

define your function `showNextQuote` like bellow

```
 function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        if(quoteIndex==quotes.length-1){ //if it's the last quote
            quotes.eq(quoteIndex).fadeIn(2000); //jsut fad-in & return
            return;
        }
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/48/)